# how to call a method with a string in vba for outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

I created a two dimensional string array.  I set up a for loop to take a string from the user and search the first column of the array.  I want to use the corresponding string from the second column of the array to call a method.  However, I can't figure out how to use a string to call a sub or the method of a class in Outlook VBA.  Any suggestions?

Comment: It would help to update your question with your existing code and some examples of the types of calls you want to make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the call by name function using the name of an objects method at runtime. The simple example below creates an object of a class and an array and then calls methods named in the second elements of the array.

In the Class Module:

```
Sub Procedure1()

MsgBox "I'm procedure1"

End Sub


Sub Procedure2()

MsgBox "I'm Procedure2"

End Sub


Sub Procedure3(ByVal sName As String)

MsgBox "Procedure 3 here " & sName

End Sub
```

In the standard module:

```
Sub Main()

Dim myArray(1 To 2, 1 To 3) As String
Dim oClass1 As Class1

Set oClass1 = New Class1
'oClass1.Procedure1

myArray(1, 1) = "Procedure1"
myArray(1, 2) = "Procedure2"
myArray(1, 3) = "Procedure3"

Call CallByName(oClass1, myArray(1, 1), VbMethod)
Call CallByName(oClass1, myArray(1, 2), VbMethod)
Call CallByName(oClass1, myArray(1, 3), VbMethod, "Graham")
Call CallByName(oClass1, myArray(1, 3), VbMethod, "user3299464")

End Sub
```